# Why is a condition $a_n \geq 0$ necessary?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, examples-counterexamples

I was given this homework

> Suppose the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ is $R$ and $a_n \geq 0$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. Prove that $\lim_{x \to R^-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nR^n$.

Now the proof is extremely easy due to the assumption $a_n \geq 0$. If RHS is finite, then LHS=RHS by Abel’s theorem. If RHS is $+\infty$, then

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to R^-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n > 
\lim_{x \to R^-} \sum_{n=1}^N a_nx^n + 0
\end{align*}

As we can pick $N$ large enough to make it large enough and we can plug in limit for finite $N$.

Why is the condition $a_n \geq 0$ necessary? I am thinking of doing

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n = \sum_{n=1}^N a_nR^n+ \sum_{n=1}^N a_n(x^n-R^n) + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_nx^n
\end{align*}

We can make the first term big. The second term can be small by sending $x$ sufficiently close to $R$. I think the problem comes from the third term.

Can someone give a concrete counter-example to why this doesn’t hold when we allow $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of $a_n \geq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the power series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^k.$ The radius of convergence is $R = 1$ and for each $x \in (-1,1)$ the series sums to $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$. Is it true or false that
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac 1{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k?$$

Comment: I see, the problem is RHS might not exist. What if we’re given RHS exists (i.e. equals $+\infty$) instead? Does it also force LHS to be $+\infty$ even if we remove $a_n \geq 0$? I just think the assumption $a_n \geq 0$ is quite unnatural.